# Does the blender video Editor has " Smart render "?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

When you render a mp4 that has already been rendered, you are losing a bit of quality every single time. A lot of video Editors have an option called " smart render " where this does not happen.

https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/smart-rendering.html as an example

[image]

I wanted to ask if the blender video editor also has something like that, to prevent recompression to save quality.

Comment: I am not sure enough to provide an official answer, but it doesn't seem so. There doesn't seem to be anything about this in [the documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/media/index.html). It is common to render animations or anything that is still being worked on in lossless formats such as EXR. They of course take a lot of more disk space, but that way you avoid the problems you are talking about.

Comment: Additionally to what @MartynasŽiemys says, if you use OpenEXR with the DWAA or DWAB codec it is not a lossless format, but there is no noticeable loss in quality and the files are even smaller than PNG files.